# VB 2010 retrieve image

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba

Good day sirs. I'm trying to retrieve a photo from my access database then load it in a PictureBox but I have this kind of problem which I can't resolve.
I have seen questions similar to mine but I can't understand the solutions given by others as I'm just a newbie. Will someone please help me correct my codes for retrieving image file from access database. Thanks
I'm using access database and Visual Basic 2010.

Here's the code:

```
Dim arrImage() As Byte
Dim myMS As New IO.MemoryStream
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * 
                                      FROM tblEmp  
                                      WHERE EmployeeID= '" 
                                          & Me.txtID.Text 
                                          & "'", con)

Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)


If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    If Not IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0).Item("Picture")) Then
        arrImage = dt.Rows(0).Item("Picture")
        For Each ar As Byte In arrImage
            myMS.WriteByte(ar)
        Next
        '
        inFrm.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(myMS)
    End If
End If
```

I'm getting a "Parameter is not valid" error from the line

```
inFrm.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(myMS)
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the line of code with this

```
inFrm.PictureBox1.PictureData = myMS.Read
```

Comment: and 'Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Read' accepts this number of arguments.' from the line
myMS.Read

Comment: got an error 'Error 1 'PictureData' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox'.